# Различные ...SdkVersion в build.gradle файле

Tags: android, android-studio

Допустим, в *build.gradle* файле есть следующие строки:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.common.app"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 18
  }
}
```

Что значит `minSdkVersion` более-менее понятно - минимальная версия уровня API, на устройствах с API ниже которой приложение не будет запускаться. А что значат остальные `...SdkVersion`: `targetSdkVersion`, `compileSdkVersion` и `buildToolsVersion`?

Да, я читала, что `targetSdkVersion` - это версия API, о которой ты думаешь, когда пишешь приложение (типа API целевого устройства), `compileSdkVersion` - это версия API для компиляции, `buildToolsVersion` - версия Android SDK build tools, но как-то это не добавляет понимания, зачем их нужно так много... А ещё же есть *Android Plugin Version* и *Gradle Version* - как они со всеми этими `...SdkVersion` соотносятся?..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Gradle version** - версия, использумая для обработки gradle скриптов, влияет на процесс сборки (косвенно зависит от Android Gradle Plugin)

**Android Gradle Plugin version** - версия плагина, для обработки секции `android { ... }` в build.gradle, влияет на процесс сборки (зависит от необходимой поддержки: например нативная поддержка лямбд из JDK8 требует 2.4.0+)

**buildToolsVersion** (рекомендуется последняя) - версия утилит (dx, aapt, etc) из `sdk/build-tools/`, которые будут использоваться для сборки (не зависит)

**minSdkVersion** - прописывается в AndroidManifest, приложение не установится, если системный SDK меньше. (не зависит)

**maxSdkVersion** (редко используется) - прописывается в AndroidManifest, приложение не установится, если системный SDK больше. (не зависит)

**compileSdkVersion** - версия android.jar, которая будет подключаться при компиляции, если будет попытка использовать API из новой версии - не скомпилируется (зависит от java кода)

**targetSdkVersion** - не влияет на компиляцию, это обещание для системы "приложение должно хорошо работать на версии Х", влияет на то, будут ли включаться legacy-механизмы (например, для разрешений при targetSdkVersion < 23). Так же может влиять на внешний вид приложения

Так же должно выполняться:
`minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion`

Comment: А Android Gradle Plugin version 2.4.0+ существует же пока только в альфа-версии, или нет?

Comment: И ещё: я всё-таки не вижу причин для того, чтобы использовать buildToolsVersion и compileSdkVersion разных версий... Может Вы можете привести примеры, когда это нужно?)

Comment: И ещё один маленький вопрос: что такое "legacy-механизмы", где об этом можно почитать?)

Comment: @Ksenia 2.4.0 закончился на версии alpha7, сейчас уже 3.0 alpha8.
compileSdk=25, build tools = 26 сейчас у большинства (т.к. при использовании compilesdk 26 надо использовать беты support-library).
legacy - это совместимость со старым. яркий пример - поведение приложений, собранных с target < 23, на андроиде 6+: там не используются runtime permissions