# При уменьшении api level c 25 на 21 появляется ошибка gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Здравствуйте , нужна помощь.
Проблема появляется при уменьшении api level приложения с 25 на 21 , как это можно исправить? При изменении на api level 25 все отлично, ошибок нет.

содержимое build.gradle 
[image: biild.gradle]

Скриншот ошибки:
[image: error]

Comment: Приложите текстом build.gradle и ошибки. Также посоветую прочитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697603/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-sdkversion-%d0%b2-build-gradle-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5/697615#697615

Comment: В чем смысл понижения compileSdkVersion? Достаточно targetSdkVersion "при уменьшении api level приложения".

Answer (score 3):

Мажорный номер версии библиотек группы `com.android.support` не может быть больше `compileSdkVersion`.

В вашем случае либо повысьте `compileSdkVersion` до 25, либо понизьте версию всем зависимостям группы `com.android.support` до 21.х.х

Comment: Понизил , опять выдаёт ошибку https://pp.userapi.com/c841222/v841222491/1ff1a/T8WroMj9RJE.jpg

Comment: 21.1.2 -- нет такой версии. 21.0.3 была последней из 21-ых.

Answer (score 1):

ты используешь ресурсы которые работают с 23 api. compileSdk поставь 25

Comment: Интересует создание проекта именно с версией api 21

Comment: min sdk оставь 21. compileSDK поставь 25. И все